# Dependency Injection error

Tags: spring, unit-testing, dependency-injection, spring-test

I get an error while running a junit test with spring.

Here is my test class :

```
    package testdao;

    import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

    import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import dao.daoImpl.DaoImpl;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:TestDao-context.xml")
public class TestDao {
    @Autowired
    private DaoImpl test1;
    @Test
    public void test() {
        try {
            test1.connect();
            assertTrue(true);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            assertTrue(false);
        }
    }
}
```

and then my xml configuration file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Uncomment and add your base-package here: <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.service"/> -->


    <!-- DAO -->
    <!-- MongoFactoryBean instance -->
    <bean id="mongoFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1" />
        <property name="port" value="27017" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mongoDbFactory"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongoFactoryBean" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="agence_voyage" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dao" class="dao.daoImpl.DaoImpl">
        <property name="mongoFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Services -->
    <bean id="service" class="service.serviceImpl.ServiceImpl">
        <property name="dao" ref="dao" />
    </bean>



<!-- Tests -->
    <bean id="testDao" class="testdao.TestDao">
        <property name="test1" ref="dao"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

so when i run it i get an ApplicationContext loading error caused by :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testDao' defined in class path resource [TestDao-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'test1' of bean class [testdao.TestDao]: Bean property 'test1' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

In addition i tried to use the @Required + add setter for the test1, but i got the same error.

Do you know what happens ?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to define the `testDao` bean. Spring will inject the `DaoImpl` into `testDao` using the `@ContextConfiguration` configuration. Just remove the test class bean from the Spring context configuration

Comment: Yes that's the solution ! Thanks Orid !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from Orid : 
"You don't need to define the testDao bean. Spring will inject the DaoImpl into testDao using the @ContextConfiguration configuration. Just remove the test class bean from the Spring context configuration "